# Multiple Database connection issue CakePHP v2.x

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP v2.x. My current Database is MySQL. My need is to connect to other     Database within a method/function written under controller. So what I did so far is add another DB connection  array $test in Config/database.php.

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host'       => 'localhost',
    'login'      => 'test',
    'password'   => 'test1',
    'database'   => 'test_portal',
    'prefix'     => ''
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource'    => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent'    => false,
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'login'     => 'dfffd_23',
    'password'  => 'dsfsd324',
    'database'  => 'testdbuser',
    'prefix'    => ''
    //'encoding'    => 'utf8',
);
}
```

I need to connect a table named 'aezips'.So I created a new Model;

```
class Aezips extends AppModel { 

  public $name      = 'Aezip'; 
  public $useDbConfig   = 'test';
  //public $useTable        = 'aezips';

}
```

In my controller added ;

```
public $uses = array('Aezip');
```

Controller having a function/method named add,

```
public function add() {


        $this->layout = NULL;
        $this->autoRender = false; //will prevent render of view



        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
             Configure::write('debug', 0); //it will avoid any extra output
          }


        //$this->Aezip->useDbConfig('test'); 

        $t = $this->Aezip->find('all');     //To fetch data from aezips table
        print_r($t);    

        print_r($this->data);



}
```

But I can't connect to Aezip table and it doesn't shows any error. Both Database residing from same server but different cpanel account.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have used the wrong name for your Model (plural instead of singular);

```
class Aezips extends AppModel {}
```

Should be:

```
class Aezip extends AppModel {}
```

And the right filename should be `app/Model/Aezip.php`

Also, be sure to enable 'debug' inside `app/Config/core.php` so that you can see the queries that are performed. Also, this will refresh the CakePHP caches more often, which will reduce the risk of using 'cached' Model definitions.

You can debug your variables using `debug($variable);` in stead of `print_r($variable);`